# Can we store multiple values for a single column in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

In my application, i want to store two strings for a single column in sqlite database i.e., two images for a same word, is there any alternative to do this other than primary and foreign key relationship?

Comment: This question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743889/sqlite-storing-multiple-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have two columns for images like:

**myTable**

```
columnWord
columnImage1
columnImage2
```

Comment: MAN, we can't save two images in one column... But we can use the above alternate solution & it will work, can you see any flaw?